# how to delete the data from the Delta Table?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I was actually trying to delete the data from the Delta table.

When i run the below query, I'm getting data around 500 or 1000 records.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 inv 
join (SELECT col1, col2, col2, min(Date) minDate, max(Date) maxDate FROM table2 a GROUP BY col1, col2, col3) aux
on aux.col1 = inv.col1 and aux.col2 = inv.col2 and aux.col3 = inv.col3 
WHERE Date between aux.minDate and aux.maxDate
```

But when i try to delete that 500 records with the below query I'm getting error with syntax.

```
DELETE FROM table1 inv 
join (SELECT col1, col2, col2, min(Date) minDate, max(Date) maxDate FROM table2 a GROUP BY col1, col2, col3) aux
on aux.col1 = inv.col1 and aux.col2 = inv.col2 and aux.col3 = inv.col3 
WHERE Date between aux.minDate and aux.maxDate
```

Please someone help me here.

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Please share also error and example data so we can provide exact answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [sql reference](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-delete-from.html):

```sql
DELETE FROM table_identifier [AS alias] [WHERE predicate]
```

You can't use `JOIN` here, so expand your where clause according to your needs.
Here are some examples:

```sql
DELETE FROM table1
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ... FROM table2 ...)

DELETE FROM table1
  WHERE table1.col1 IN (SELECT ... FROM table2 WHERE ...)

DELETE FROM table1
  WHERE table1.col1 NOT IN (SELECT ... FROM table2 WHERE ...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gatear :) It works. My bad i have missed it.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please don't forget to mark the accepted answer. Thanks!